# Remote connection to sql server with php

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, odbc, centos7

I am trying to connect to sql server from my linux server with php. from my local system with os:windows my connection was successfull but from os:linux server I couldn't connect.

**LOCAL**

I,ve been installed extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll in XAMPP and installed ODBC Driver and my connection and queries was successfull

**SERVER**

in my linux Centos 7 server
I installed sqlsrv driver and ODBC,
I think driver is ok because functions is recognized **but** give me errors in connection

here is my error

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "HYT00"
    ["SQLSTATE"]=>
    string(5) "HYT00"
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    ["code"]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    string(63) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired"
    ["message"]=>
    string(63) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "08001"
    ["SQLSTATE"]=>
    string(5) "08001"
    [1]=>
    int(10057)
    ["code"]=>
    int(10057)
    [2]=>
    string(73) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749"
    ["message"]=>
    string(73) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "08001"
    ["SQLSTATE"]=>
    string(5) "08001"
    [1]=>
    int(10057)
    ["code"]=>
    int(10057)
    [2]=>
    string(330) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online."
    ["message"]=>
    string(330) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online."
  }
}
```

I also config /etc/odbc.ini and write these lines into it

```
[MyMSSQLServer]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description=My MS SQL Server
Trace=No
Server=111.222.333.444
[ODBC]
Pooling=No
```

and added

```
[ODBC]
Pooling=No
```

to /etc/odbcinst.ini

but i can't connect to sql server.

this is my connection code

```
$server = '111.111.222.333';
or $server = '111.111.222.333\sqlexpress, 1433'

        $connectionInfo = array( 
            "Database"  => "test_data",
            "UID"       => "test",
            "PWD"       => "123456",
        );

        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

        if($conn == false):
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump((sqlsrv_errors()));
            die();
        endif;
```

Comment: By default SQL Express does not accept remote connections (see https://support.appliedi.net/kb/how-do-i-remotely-connect-to-my-mssql-express-server/). You should not be using SQL Express for any kind of live application anyway, it's only designed for use during development.

Comment: Check the Server Protocols in the SQL Server [version] Configuration Manager tool. Depending on the installed version you'll probably find that TCP/IP is not enabled, or it is configured to only listen on localhost [127.0.0.1] so is not accepting network connections.

Comment: thank you, I checked TCP/IP and was enabled in all ip and other ips @AlwaysLearning

Comment: I have to Do this, @ADyson

Comment: `I have to Do this`... No, you don't. SQL Express is not a live tool. Do the job properly, or not at all. If you don't want to pay a SQL Server license then switch to an open-source DB engine. If your server is a test server then fair enough, but you need to configure SQL express for remote access and also ensure there's a network path to it - e.g. if the SQL Express server is on your local machine, and the server is on a hosting account elsewhere (not in your LAN) then there will probably be a firewall and/or NAT router in between the two machines.

Comment: I could connect to sql server with php from local computer (localhost), my problem is when I put my codes on linux server, sql server give me login timeout, I also connect to sql server with `spring` and `Asp.net`. @ADyson

Comment: Yes we already understand the problem in principle. You need to double-check you've enabled the remote access properly, and depending on the location of the database (which you haven't clarified yet) you may need to configure your firewall/router adequately too.

Comment: `I also connect to sql server with spring and Asp.net`... from where? From local, or from the server?

Comment: `depending on the location of the database (which you haven't clarified yet)` sql DB is in a  windows server on internet, my php and mysql DB is in another server @ADyson

Comment: Both of the remote access and the DB are on separate servers @ADyson

Comment: Ok. Have you also checked whether your Linux server / hosting company allows outbound connections on port 1433?

Comment: No I have not checked what you said, Thank you. I'll check it out and tell you more... for help @ADyson